# Specify all Makefile targets as .PHONY with wildcard

Tags: makefile

All targets in my Makefile aren't real files, is it valid to specify just `.PHONY: %`. Or should I list all targets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to list all the targets that are meant to be phony targets as prerequisites of the `.PHONY` target instead of just writing `.PHONY: %`.

---

`.PHONY: %` doesn't do what you think it does (i.e., *turning every target into a phony target*).

As an example, consider the following makefile:

```
.PHONY: %

foo:
    @echo creating $@
    @touch $@
```

For this makefile above:

```
$ make
creating foo
$ make
make: 'foo' is up to date.
```

Therefore, the target `foo` is not turned into a phony target by having `.PHONY: %` in your makefile. Otherwise, `foo`'s recipe would have been executed, since phony targets are always outdated.